# Функция добавления в друзья Java Spring

Tags: java, база-данных, spring, jsp

На стажировке дали задание сделать веб приложение с авторизацией, регистрацией, добавления в друзья и отображения списка друзей. Авторизацию и регистрацию сделал по видео (Spring security: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iivY8B5A0Tk&t=143s).

Для отображение друзей сделал отдельную jsp страницу по адресу /freinds. Все данные лежат в базе данных PostgreSQL. В базе имеются 2 таблицы:

1. users(id, login, password)
2. friends(first_friend (это id юзера из первой таблицы), second_friend (тоже id из первой таблицы но уже другой юзер) и status) (status - это число от 0 до 2, 0-заявка, 1-принял, 2-отказал. Вроде логично.

Но подкачала реализация, из-за того что мало знаком со Spring'om. Как связать таблицы user с таблицей friends?

Таблицы user и friends привязаны к соответстующим классам через @Entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users") 
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
```

и

```
@Entity
@Table(name="friends")
public class Friends {
@Column(name = "friend_one")
String friend_one;
@Column(name = "friend_two")
String friend_two;
@Column(name ="status")
int status;
```

Как соединить ячейки friend_one к id и friend_two к другому id (это же foreign key?)
Не знаю как обратиться к базе через Sql, и как сделать statement. Потому что авторизация и регистрация сделаны через model или bean'ы.

И подскажите как отобразить данные из базы на jsp станице. Мой пример:

```
<table>
  <c:forEach items="${friends}" var="friend"> 
    <tr>
      <td>${friend.username}</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="action" value="delete"/></td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: копайте в сторону many to many hibernate(JPA), spring здесь не причем. Вам получается придется подвязать таблицу USERS саму на себя

Answer (score 1):

Сущность `Friends` вообще не нужна. `User` может и должен ссылаться на других `User`:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<User> friends;

    public void setFriends(Set<User> friends) {
        this.friends = friends;
    }

    public Set<User> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }
}
```

И тогда в jsp

```
<table>
  <c:forEach items="${someUser.friends}" var="friend"> 
    <tr>
      <td>${friend.username}</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="action" value="delete"/></td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

А заявки на дружбу вместе с их статусами лучше хранить в отдельной сущности типа

```
@Entity
class Invite {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private User from;

    @Column
    private User to;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private InviteStatus status;
}
```

Comment: А можете объяснить что делает код и как работает? Хотелось бы понять логику

Comment: Вы не пройдёте стажировку, если не будете делать попыток разобраться самостоятельно. Вот [первая же ссылка в Google](http://alextretyakov.blogspot.ru/2013/07/jpa-mapping-tipa-mnogie-ko-mnogim.html) по запросу JPA @ManyToMany.